# jsf 2 session not replicating on cluster?

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, cluster-computing, seam3

I read some question here some days ago that made me understand that a view scoped bean is on the session. Is this right?

I am asking because I have an jsf 2 + seam 3 + cdi app that on a single node works perfectly with the view scoped beans, and as soon as it is put on a cluster, I get one request working and the next is a view expired exception.

So, am I correct to assume that my session is not replicating correctly? On my web.xml I have the distributable tag. I am using jboss 6.1. Should I do anything else, on the app or jboss (apart from using the all context) to make it work?

Or I cannot use view scoped beans on a clustered environment?

Comment: Just adding the load balancing is made by apache mod_jk

Comment: Stumbled here as I'm having same issues. Although I'm trying to get fail over working when a jvm dies. Your issue is more than likely to do with sticky sessions. Most load balancers have this option. Yours is most likely hitting server 1 first and server 2 on the next request. Replication is failing however.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening, but I dont seem to get it working. Apache is configured for sticky sessions and so is jboss, so I am really lost here

Comment: Might be worth checking that Cookie is set correctly with jsessionid etc on 1st request. Might also be worth checking that IP address is not dynamically changing somehow.

Comment: Right now I just saw a line on mod_jk log  Could not find worker with name 'jk-status'. I my node names are node1, node2

Comment: Would you mind showing us your configuration files?